# Access returning invalid data for specific column names

Tags: sql, ms-access

While it's true that I have not used Access as a DBMS for a pretty long time, the behavior I see is simply unacceptable. Here is my query:

```
SELECT MONTH([My_DateTime_Column]) AS [Period] FROM [My_Table]
```

If I use [Month] or [Period] as alias, the returned value is a **date/time**, but if I use [Month1] or [Period1], the returned value is **int** (correct). What's going on here?

Comment: Could this be something happening at the application level?  I don't think MS Access is going to change the type based on the alias.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No I'm using it directly in Access 2010.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue by running queries in Access 2010. When I copy and paste your query into the Query Design window and run it I get an integer (i.e., it has a`VarType()` of `2` which is `vbInteger`).

Comment: @dotNET I'm seeing the same responses  as Gord in 32 bit Access 2010 on Windows 10 64 bit.  Have you applied all the latest updates for both Windows and Office?

Comment: @GordThompson: One thing. My base table has a column named `[month - period]`. Could this be causing something?

Comment: It's possible, but it doesn't seem to affect my results when I run the query in your question. Can you create a small sample table that represents a [mcve]?

Comment: What exactly is the returned value for a given input date? What language is your Office installation?